# How to convert string date to Date object as per the System's Regional date time format settings?

Tags: java, date, datetime, formatting

In my project,i am using object of `Date` class,
for example

```
Date date = Date(dateInStringForm);[Though it is deprecated]
```

It is working perfect with `IST[Indian Standard Time]` but when i change the settings in Region & Language in control panel `[Operating system : Windows7]` to any other country for example, portugal then it is throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. How can we make this conversion generic ?

Following is my trial example code,

import java.util.Date;

public class GenericDateTime {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //  Date date = new Date("Jan 20, 2015 3:19:52 PM"); //Indian Standard Time Format
    Date date = new Date("20/Jan/2015 15:19:51"); //Portugese Time Format
    System.out.println("Date Object Form--->>>" + date);
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Ambiguous Dates in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552643/parsing-ambiguous-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its has nothing to do with Timezone. You're  giving a different format than a `Date()` would allow and can parse. There is no generic way that will accept **any kind of** date format without **not knowing the format** before converting.

So to accept any specific format you can use `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        try {
            Date date = dateFormat.parse("20/Jan/2015 15:19:51");
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


  }
```

Comment: Thank you Saif,for now it is working fine. But i will get back to you for difficulties if any,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing date as String you can use SimpleTimeFormat to specify date format and pass date string as UTC time. If you are free to use external libs [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) would be best option for you.